# Move a script to its own js file

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to move the angular to its own `.js` file, so I looked at [Using an HTML button to call a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function).

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doFunction();" />
```

As far as I understand, an event has to be triggered when I click on the button, so I tried following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-click.asp) example on w3schools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click Me!</button>

<p>{{ count }}</p>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

It simply counts the number of times a button has been clicked and it works. However, when I move the `<script>` to its own .js, the function is not found. Am I missing something? a dependency perhaps?

New files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click Me!</button>

<p>{{ count }}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**.js**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting? And what does your html look like when you move the angularjs code to its own file?

Comment: @Tyler ,The HTML file looks the same just remove `<script> whats between </script>` (Add whats removed without the tags) to a .js file. ( I will edit question)

Comment: You have an answer @TonyTannous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you access external JavaScript arrays in an html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531704/how-can-you-access-external-javascript-arrays-in-an-html-file)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I do agree it is very similar, but with angularjs, you do need to be aware that it should be below the angular script.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @Tyler Is that really a huge leap to ask someone to make? How about https://stackoverflow.com/q/36988823/215552 then? Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/29035843/215552? Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/34729022/215552? I could go on...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've seen it cause plenty of people issues. I'm not trying to start a flame war, only pointing out that the question(s) you linked aren't exact duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two problems.

First, in your `.js` file you can remove the `<script>` tags. You only need this for javascript in html files.

Second, in your `.html` file, you need to add a reference to your script file. This needs to go below the angular script since it is dependent on that script, so just add, `<script src="[link to your script file]"></script>` to your html right below the angular script.

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click Me!</button>

<p>{{ count }}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
});
```

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade I write angularjs apps for a living, this is the only way I've ever seen it included in a separate file. Your answer and I'm guessing your understanding of how browsers handle these sorts of things seems to be fundamentally flawed. I think you are confusing CORS requests with script tags.

Comment: This may be different between raw js and angular. @Tyler